# Can I sort a 2d vector by row first value?

Tags: c++

I want to sort rows of a 2d vector based on the first value, second value if the first one is the same and so on
For example

```
-8 2 9

-8 1 10

-6 3 10

-5 2 10
```

I want to sort this in to

```
-8 1 10

-8 2 10

-6 3 10

-5 2 10
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Yes: `std::sort` with a custom comparer

Comment: You don't even need a custom compare function. `std::vector` already does [lexicographical compares](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) by default.

Answer (score -1):

```
stable_sort(vectorName.begin(), vectorName.end());;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.